# Trigger click jumps to element (tab)

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and wanna use `trigger('click')` on some element (tab in my situation). Have not found a solution for my issue. Element is on bottom of a page and using `trigger('click')` on this element page is scrolling/jumping to this element. How to do it with out scrolling/jumping?

```
$('#element').trigger('click');
```

Comment: has `#element` an `href="#"`?

Comment: @Roy `href="#description"`

Comment: I strongly recommend you immediately stop using jQuery and learn the native JS DOM API instead. jQuery will introduce alot of convenience-based misconceptions in your head and in 2019, in 99.8% of cases jQuery is no longer necessary, and honestly, unwanted, too. And for your problem, jQuery is creating it's own custom event instead of the native DOM events.

Comment: @kewin432 That's why the scroll to the div `id="description"`. What suppose to do the click? run a function? go to another page?

Comment: @Roy on page load function opens tabs using `trigger('click')`

Comment: @kewin432 Instead of "clicking" **maybe** you should add the `active` class  to the opened tab/content -`$('#element').addClass('active');$('#description').addClass('active')`-, to avoid the scroll/jumping.

Comment: @Roy how `addClass('active')` will open tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the element from performing its default operations/actions when clicked on—in this case, jumping to another element—you need to bind an event handler that nullifies that, i.e. by calling `event.preventDefault()` in the onclick handler:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Proof-of-concept example:

```js
$('#trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#element').trigger('click');
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#element')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click triggered');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500vh;
}

.spacer {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="trigger">Trigger click on link below</a>
<br />
<a href="#description" id="element">Go to description</a>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Of course, all this can be done using native JS:

```
const el = document.getElementById('element');
el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @kewin432 Check the example to see Terry's code works.

Comment: @connexo Had to rollback your edit, because it is not the use case OP described.

Comment: I rolled back so I could edit properly. You haven't seen the end result at that point in time. Feel free to improve if you think it could be clearer or more helpful.

Comment: Mmm, not working... Page loads and jumps to element when `trigger('click')` fires(((